# ffmpeg recode video AND remove audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to recode a video **and** remove the audio.
The option `-c:an` should do this job, but I receive the error: **At least one output file must be specified**.

## Does not work

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\Users\___\Videos\DSC_7056.MOV" `
-c:v libx264 `
-preset slow `
-crf 18 `
-c:an `
"C:\Users\___\Videos\out.mkv"
```

## Works, but audio is not removed

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\Users\___\Videos\DSC_7056.MOV" `
-c:v libx264 `
-preset slow `
-crf 18 `
-c:a aac -b:a 128k `
"C:\Users\___\Videos\out.mkv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\Users\___\Videos\DSC_7056.MOV" `
-c:v libx264 `
-preset slow `
-crf 18 `
-an `
"C:\Users\___\Videos\out.mkv"
```

`-c:an` is not valid syntax.